# How to disable drawer layout from one side?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have made a double drawer layout **without an actionbar** something like this:

[Using Navigation Drawer without TitleBar or ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735621/using-navigation-drawer-without-titlebar-or-actionbar/21155913#21155913)

My requirement is to disable the drawer on right when drawer on left is open & vice versa. So I'm hiding the right drawer button when left drawer is open & vice versa and that works fine.

But the problem is, even when I hide a button(left or right), the drawer still opens with horizontal swipe(right to left swipe). **So how do I prevent the drawer from opening from swipe??**

And since I'm doing it without ActionBarDrawerToggle inbuilt functions like

```
setOnDrawerOpenListener
setOnDrawerCloseListener
```

are not available.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this may help you...

```
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
            if(view == rightDrawerView) {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, leftDrawerView);
            } else if(view == leftDrawerView) {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, rightDrawerView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            if(view == rightDrawerView) {
                 drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, leftDrawerView);
            } else if(view == leftDrawerView) {
                 drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, rightDrawerView);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This answer is almost perfect. But, when I close my left drawer, the right drawer "open-with-swipe" functionality must get enabled again. For that:
1. Write the exact onDrawerOpened(View view) code in onDrawerClosed(View view)
2. Change the mode to DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED

Comment: @GopalRao where are you bro??

Comment: how to hide the drawer layout and with it the navigation view?

Answer (score 9):

Try this

[`setDrawerLockMode (int lockMode, View drawerView)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode%28int,%20android.view.View%29)

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN, yourDrawer)
```

Comment: But where should I write the code you've given me. The answer to that is given by Gopal Rao.