# Navigation Drawer covers Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I wanted Navigation Drawer in my application but **I don't want Navigation Drawer to covers my Action Bar**. Action bar should be visible always. I searched internet and i got some solution from stackoverflow and some blogs but all are same. I referred this solution [Using Navigation Drawer without TitleBar or ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735621/using-navigation-drawer-without-titlebar-or-actionbar), but still its same. As they mentioned in the answer, i gave `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` first then `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`. 
Android studio design preview is showing correctly but in realtime mobile phone actionbar covered by navigation drawer.

In Android Studio

[image: Android Studio]

In Mobile Phone

[image]

and here is the **activity_album_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".activity.AlbumDashboardActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_album_dashboard" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_album_dashboard"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_album_dashboard_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and nav_header_album_dashboard.xml (i don't want header, so just kept empty LinearLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set your navigation view , add layout_below: toolbar

Comment: check my answer I updated your xml. just copy and paste that in your layout file

Comment: remove this line  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from drawer layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put you drawer layout after toolbar ... Just Change your layout like this... and if you don't need header then why using any layout for header just remove `app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_album_dashboard"` from navigation View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.AlbumDashboardActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/content_album_dashboard" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_album_dashboard"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_album_dashboard_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. But **status bar** was covering by navigation drawer. I removed `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`, and its worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.AlbumDashboardActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_album_dashboard" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_album_dashboard"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_album_dashboard_drawer" />
```

in NavigationView set margintop equal to size of toolbar. it work for me