# android navigation menu covers actionbar

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have an xml layout that contains an actionbar, a navigation menu and a main content.

The action bar contains a search area and a button to toggle the navigation menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://szchemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleTheme"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/menu2" />
```

This is how the app looks like

[image]

When I show the menu it covers my actionbar

[image]

I tried adding this to the navigation drawer

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    .....
    .....
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation Drawer covers Actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373946/navigation-drawer-covers-actionbar)

Comment: This is how it's supposed to be

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282295/navigation-drawer-below-actionbar

Answer (score 0):

You should move DrawerLayout as top parent and move Toolbar out of DrawerLayout content container. In short this looks like:

- RelativeLayout
- ---------Toolbar
- -----------DrawerLayout
- --------------ContentView
- -------------------DrawerList.

  ```
  <RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/top_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <include
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      layout="@layout/toolbar" />

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/content_frame"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/background_color" />

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/drawer"
          android:layout_width="260dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

`important:`
    However, `Material Design` guidelines state that `Navigation Drawer` should be above the `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem too before. Here's how it looks now:

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cpb_white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
...
...

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>
...
...

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationview"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/cpb_white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_mainmenu">


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="HomePageTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#7200d9</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#7200d9</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#d810a7</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#f44336</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```