# Drawer Navigation (adding title of listview and images)

Tags: android

I was using the drawer navigation which was in android development website, but it didnt show the title or header or image in the listview, so can u show me how to add title and image in the drawer navigation which was in android development website didnt have?
[Like this example](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/05/creating-navigation-drawer.html)

Here are some of the code:`<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->

    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/Black"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`

Comment: use a custom listview. google search the same you will find many examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create custom Adapter class with your custom layout and set that adapter to list view. Check the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874826/how-to-add-icons-adjacent-to-titles-for-android-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for your implementations:  [From GITHUB](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

it will allow you to put your custom layout in your sliding menu.

Thank you,

Comment: You have NavigationDrawer which can be used for the same. Why do you want to use a external library?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution :

in your project, create a new xml file.and paste below code in the xml viewer.after that in the graphical view you can see your customised list view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp" 
android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>
```

and go to your list view adapter [because in your navigation drawer you are using a list view to show the menu items.] in gat view method change the layout for your newly created layout [the list item that we created now]

this is my get view method.it might be different from your getview method.but i guess this will help you.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item_old, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
        txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    }else{
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: it is an array which is contains the names should be shown in the navigation list. such as Home,Settings etc