# Customize Navigation Drawer and Drawer items

Tags: android, menuitem, navigation-drawer

How to customize **Navigation Drawer** menu items like the picture :

[image]

and need to disable some drawer items on login status. if user is not login the disabled menu items text color will grey and the background of item color will changed. And non disabled items color will white how to implement Navigation Drawer

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is this waht you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874826/how-to-add-icons-adjacent-to-titles-for-android-navigation-drawer

Comment: In your drawer items list, mark your desire item as non clickable. For this in your adapter   check for position of perticular item and set that item textview.setenable(false)

Answer (score 0):

you can edit these files inside your project to costumize it as you wished:

layout/nav_header_main.xml

layout/app_bar_main.xml

menu/activity_main_drawer.xml